# Best way of nesting laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel-4

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('home/{menu_slug}', 'HomeController@showMenuContents');
Route::get('home/{menu_slug}/{submenu_slug}', 'HomeController@showSubmenuContents');
```

I am a very beginner to laravel, in fact I started yesterday. I have heard of nesting routes. I have seen other nesting routes and laravel docs too but I find them quite confusing. How can it be implemented to the routes above.

Comment: What is the problem? What is wrong what the code you have?

Comment: Its working perfect, I want to know how this code could be nested in laravel routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'home'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/{menu_slug}', 'HomeController@showMenuContents');
    Route::get('/{menu_slug}/{submenu_slug}', 'HomeController@showSubmenuContents');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'home'], function()
 {
   Route::get('/{menu_slug}/{submenu_slug}', 'HomeController@showSubmenuContents');
   Route::get('/{menu_slug}', 'HomeController@showMenuContents');
   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');  
 }
```